# Does altium have common symbols?

Tags: altium, symbol

Does Altium have common symbols such as opamps, diodes, capictors, inductors that one could use to make their own symbol? Seems like an obvious thing to do.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think Altium has basic symbols specfically for use in building new schematic symbols, but you can certainly edit existing symbols and use them to help create new symbols to suit your needs.

Comment: I realised I can't copy the symbol unlesss it's from another schematic library. However, I don't know how to access the miscleanous library as a schematic library so I can't copy the symbols accross.

Answer (score 0):

use altium vault explorer.it has a lot of components ready to use.

Comment: Thanks. How would I copy them accross to the my schematic library though?

Comment: from schematic edit - make schematic library

Comment: Where is schematic edit?